# Iterating records from DB (first record repeats)

Tags: python, django

I have a application where a Paper(Paper would be a library) has multiple books. I want to display a sidebar that lists the books by title:

```
HOBIT
LOTR
```

When I browse localhost I get a sidebar with just one record repeating itself:

```
HOBIT 
HOBIT
HOBIT
HOBIT
HOBIT
```

I think something must be wrong with my loop in nav.html.

I am quite new to Python and Django, i reed a lot about looping on python, django documentation and stack overflow , but I am having problems implementing it to my current code. I am sorry if I posted to much code, but I wanted you to see the bigger picture.

Thanks for your time.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Paper

def index(request):
    paper_list = Paper.objects.all()
    context = {'paper_list': paper_list}
    return render(request, 'papers/index.html', context)

def detail(request, slug):
    paper = Paper.objects.get(slug=slug)
    context = {'paper': paper}
    return render(request, 'papers/detail.html', context)
```

nav.html

```
<nav class="menu" id="theMenu">
<div class="menu-wrap" data-spy="scroll">
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="{% url 'papers:index' %}">MY LIBRARY</a></h1>
        <i class="icon-remove menu-close"></i>
            {% for slug in paper.slug %}
                <a href="{% url 'detail' slug=paper.slug %}">{{ paper.title }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
</div>
<div id="menuToggle"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></div>
```

index.html

```
{% block h1 %}
<div class="box first">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
             {% for paper in paper_list %}
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                    <div class="center">
                        <a href="{{ paper.slug }}"  i class="icon-credit-card icon-md icon-color1"></a></li>
                        <h4>{{ paper.title }}
                        <p>{{ paper.description }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

detail.html

```
{% extends "master2.html"  %}

{% block h1 %}
    <div id="g">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <h3>{{ paper.title }}</h3> 
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="col-xs-12 "><p>{{ paper.large_description }}</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block title  %} Detail {% endblock %}
```

master2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link href="/static/font.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/static/font-awesome.min.css "rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/static/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>        
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0" data-target="#theMenu"> 
            {% include "nav.html" %}           
            {% include "header2.html" %}
            {% block h1 %}{% endblock %}
        <script src="/static/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/main2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Paper(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    large_description = RichTextField(max_length=3000)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save_in(self):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)

        super(test, self).save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your nav.html

```
{% for slug in paper.slug %}
    <a href="{% url 'detail' slug=paper.slug %}">{{ paper.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

In that line your are looping over a string, you should put there something like:

```
{% for paper in paper_list %}
    <a href="{% url 'detail' slug=paper.slug %}">{{ paper.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I've already tried that. It does not appear any records then.

Comment: Add to your detail view context {'paper': paper, 'paper_list': Paper.objects.all()}